# Выполнение задачи, после завершения предыдущей

Tags: java, очередь, task, execute

Приложение, парсит директорию, находит нужные файлы и добавляет их названия в массив. 
Далее надо организовать их поочередную обработку, решение с выставлением таймаута перед запуском обработки второго файла не годится, надо именно чтобы предыдущий файл обработался, далее запустилась обработка следующего файла из массива. p.s. в коде небольшая каша, я только учусь.

```
public void exportProducer(ArrayList<String> findedFiles) {
    if (findedFiles.size() != 0) {

        for (String fileName : findedFiles) {
            queue.add(() -> {
                //export
                progressBar1.setValue(0);
                progressBar1.setString("0%");
                String selectedFile4Auto = config.getPathForImport() + "/" + fileName;
                setRowCount = rowCount.getRowCount(selectedFile4Auto);
                model.addElement("Opening: " + fileName + "." + newline);
                textArea1.setModel(model);

                inputAllCorrectNums = new FindAllCorrectNumbers();
                String pathForExport = config.getPathForExport() + "/" + fileName;
                inputAllCorrectNums.getAllCorrectNums((selectedFile4Auto), setRowCount);

                inputAllCorrectNums.getPropertyChangeSupport().addPropertyChangeListener("state", (evt) -> {
                    if (evt.getNewValue().equals(SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE)) {
                        try {
                            importedData = inputAllCorrectNums.get();
                            System.out.println("Export to File");
                            File selectedFile = new File(config.getPathForExport() + "/" + fileName);
                            exportToFile.exportFile(importedData, selectedFile);
                            model.addElement("Exporting: " + fileName + "." + newline);
                            textArea1.setModel(model);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        inputAllCorrectNums.cancel(true);

                    }
                });
                doWorkForCorrectNums();
            });
        }
    }

}

public void autoExport() {
    Thread queueTread = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            try {
                queue.take().run();
                System.out.println("add queue");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    queueTread.start();
}
```

Решил вопрос следующим образом. Помог Паттерн Observer на Java - Наблюдатель
 http://www.javenue.info/post/76
-Убрал Очередь.
-Убрал цикл forEach. 
-Добавил notifyListeners в область где SwingWorker отвечает что завершил работу, после чего счетчиком проверятся содержимое массива, если array.size() < счетчика, то exportProducer выполняется еще раз и так до того как счетчик не будет равен длине массива.

Comment: Если у вас поочередная обработка, то зачем вам очереди? Делайте всё внутри `for (String fileName : findedFiles)` по очереди

Comment: я вызываю классы(методы), inputAllCorrectNums и exportToFile которые могут долго выполнять свою работу. и нужно запускать следующую задачу только после того как они завершат свою работу. если не ожидать, то они перезаписывают перезаписывают друг друга в экспортируемом файле.

Comment: Что значит вызываете классы? Если у вас поочередное выполнение, то вы можете это делать просто в цикле forEach, как у вас и есть `for (String fileName : findedFiles)` Если вам нужно выполнять параллельно всё, то да, тогда можно очереди использовать. Но и в таком случае, очередь нужна лишь, если вы должны обращаться к 1 "узкому" участку в коде. Например, если вы можете многопоточно выполнить весь цикл `for` но лишь в 1 файл вам нужно записывать результат. Тогда, чтобы все потоки, которые сделали обработку ваших файлов, записали результат в 1 файл и нужна очередь. ПОнятно? )))

Comment: Написал после вашего изменения. В любом случае, если вы будете последовательно выполнять, у вас поток будет ожидать выполнение всех методов. Это может занять месяц ( гипотетически) но программа обработает файл за файлом в рамках forEach и без всяких дополнительных потоков.

Comment: Dred, я пробовал сделать, то о чем вы говорите, но нет. файлы обрабатываются, но при экспорте все файлы получают данные из последнего обработанного. т.е. пример: было 4 файла, все 4 файла были поочередно импортированы, также было экспортировано 4 файла, они имеют те же названия но содержат данные последнего импортированного файла (хотя тут возможно ошибаюсь, не проверив написал, они содержат данные одного и из файлов т.е. подгужаются разные данные, получаю одни и те же данные во всех файлах)

Comment: Вы используете этот код, что у вас в вопросе?

Comment: это лишь часть. но да, он используется.

Comment: Просто, как улучшение. Вы уже объявили `String pathForExport` используйте его тут `File selectedFile = new File(pathForExport)`. Что у вас делает  `exportToFile.exportFile(importedData, selectedFile);` ? И попробуйте делать это все без очереди, просто  в цикле.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте декомпозировать ваш код и сделать несколько отдельных маленьких методов. Это облегчит его чтение и понимание.

Обработка файлов может быть легко распараллелена следующим подходом:

```
List<Path> paths = Arrays.asList(Paths.get("file1.txt"), Paths.get("file2.txt"));

paths.forEach(path -> {
        try {
            Files
                    .lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                    .parallel()
                    .forEach(this::performLine);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error while performing file: " + path);
        }
});


private void performLine(String line) {
    //do some work
}
```

Comment: По логике моей программы, этот вариант мне не подходит, либо мне надо переделывать, то что уже работает. Спасибо!